Is there a way to prioritize or make Bluetooth device connections "sticky" on an Android phone?
I have a Samsung Android phone with about a half dozen paired Bluetooth devices. The devices are: My car, a Wireless Android Auto dongle, hearing aids, a Bluetooth headset, my Android watch, and another car.
I have had a problem for years now that I can't find a solution for: While using Android Auto in my car (USB hard wired or AA wireless), the phone will randomly switch Bluetooth connections to one of the other paired audio devices, which spontaneously causes the Android Auto connection to drop. For example, the Bluetooth connection will drop from the car and switch to my hearing aids, resulting in Android Auto disconnecting ... until it may randomly switch connections back to the car and Android Auto reconnects.
I have also had issues where a phone call initially connected via my hearing aids will randomly drop after a few minutes to my Android watch.
Is there a way to prioritize Bluetooth connections on an Android phone - or make the connections "sticky" - so that an established Bluetooth connection doesn't randomly drop to another device?
Thanks!

This app claims to prioritize Bluetooth connections // Not tested by me

The Bluetooth Prioritizer app (btprio) was apparently removed from the Google Play store.
I have tried the other suggested solutions, and neither of them worked for me.

I use Bluetooth Audio Connect Widget especially for this purpose. I use it for years now, always works like a charm. I used it on my previous phone on Andorid 9, and now on my current phone on Android 13.
How it works: You install it, and you create a widget for the devices you want to give priority to.
Now, all you have to do is enable bluetooth and then check that widget to see if it was connected to the device you want (even if it automatically connects to your Android Auto from normal bluetooth). If the widget does not say its connected, press it to connect. This ensures that it stays connected.
You can create multiple widgets so you can switch between multiple devices. Do note that the widget can decide that it connects to multiple devices. If that happens, press once on a connected device that you don't want to connect, so its widget changes. It no longer gets priority to connect.
You also have the option to automatically enable/disable bluetooth and other varios options.
Another note, in order to configure the app, you need bluetooth to be enabled.

Thanks for the app suggestion!
Will the app prevent lower-priority devices from randomly reconnecting if they aren't manually enabled in the widget?

They will as long as your current bluetooth device does not for whatever reason disconnect by themselves. That said, if that happens, and the bluetooth device automatically goes back into pairing mode, the connection should be reestablished automatically.

After using the Bluetooth Audio Connect Widget for about a month, this app did the trick for me - If I tap on the BACW desktop widget for my hearing aids when I get into my car, the Bluetooth connection between my phone and hearing aids is disabled until I tap the widget again or turn off/on my hearing aids later. I haven't seen the random AA disconnection problems like I did in the past.

Yeah, me neither. I've tried quite a few apps, and this one seems to work the most reliable keeping a connection alive.
